# change multiple select text "x items"

Tags: html, select, multiple-select

When using a multiple select element, on mobile after choosing 2 items, the field will show "2 items", is there a way to customize the word items, on desktop this isn't the case.

```
   <select name="procedures[]" id="procedures" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Chemical peel</option>
      <option value="6">Breast augmentation</option>
      <option value="7">Breast lift</option>
      <option value="8">Breast reduction</option>
    </select>
```